# Google Play Console service accounts not appearing after a refresh

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-play-console, service-accounts, google-iam

I have successfully linked my project from the google cloud to the play console. I had 5 service accounts already on google cloud that I made before linking my projects, and all of them appeared successfully on google play console.

I needed a new service account, so i created it in google cloud, gave it a few permissions (pub/sub admin and monitoring viewer). I created this service account and generated a key (I need for a separate use). I hit refresh on the play console under the API section but the new service account did not appear. I waited 5 days and after another refresh it is still not appearing. What can i do to resolve this issue?

Under the IAM section of google cloud it shows permissions (X/Y excess permissions) for each listed email address, except for the newly added service accounts. I have a published version of my app on android production and i tried to add the new accounts after it was published.

I have tried to make new service accounts multiple times with varying levels of permissions, and i have tried waiting for a few days for the issue to resolve itself in case it relies on google somehow.